# Eloquent query build of laravel cashier, why was it done this way?

Tags: eloquent

i was looking at the source code of laravel cashier and saw this:

```
   /**
     * Get a subscription instance by name.
     *
     * @param  string  $subscription
     * @return \Laravel\Cashier\Subscription|null
     */
    public function subscription($subscription = 'default')
    {
        return $this->subscriptions->sortByDesc(function ($value) {
            return $value->created_at->getTimestamp();
        })
        ->first(function ($value) use ($subscription) {
            return $value->name === $subscription;
        });
    }
```

why the 2 anonymous functions? why not just (bit naive):

```
$this->subscriptions->where('name', $value)
```